# With Rails 3, Ruby 1.9.2, how do I make a table sortable on a column that is NOT a DB column?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

It is easy, following this railscast http://railscasts.com/episodes/240-search-sort-paginate-with-ajax to be able to create a table that sorts based on columns that exist in my database.  but I have other columns I show in my table that are not database columns and I still need to sort by those columns.

For example, I have multiple columns to make up a donors name (prefix1, first_name1,middle_name1,last_name1, suffix1, prefix2, first_name2,middle_name2,last_name2,suffix2, company).  I defined in my model "who_donated" which is a combination of the actual table columns using some rules I was given.  So basically my donors table I display has 1 field for who_donated and I would like to be able to sort on that field.

How can I sort on a column of my view table if that column isn't an actual column in my database table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because I had so many different ways of gathering information to put in the columns I need to sort by and because there will be many 100ks of rows possibly to sort by, I decided to put as much of the work on the mysql server as possible to do the sorting for every case.

This is how I solved it... I pretty much followed railscasts 228 and 240 for the initial setup:http://asciicasts.com/episodes/228-sortable-table-columns and http://asciicasts.com/episodes/240-search-sort-paginate-with-ajax

Then I made a few modifications as follows.

donors_controller:

```
def last_sort_column
  params[:sort].blank? ? 'created_at' :  params[:sort]
end 

def sort_column
  case 
    when Donor.column_names.include?(params[:sort]) then params[:sort]
    when params[:sort] == 'Donors' then 
        'concat(prefix1,first_name1,middle_name1,last_name1,suffix1,
        prefix2,first_name2,middle_name2,last_name2,suffix2,company)' 
    when params[:sort] == 'First Donated' then
         '(select min(donations.created_at) from donations where donations.donor_id = donors.id)'       
    when params[:sort] == 'Last Donated' then
         '(select max(donations.created_at) from donations where donations.donor_id = donors.id)'       
    when params[:sort] == 'Times Donated' then
         '(select count(*) from donations where donations.donor_id = donors.id)'       
    when params[:sort] == 'Total Amount' then
         '(select sum(amount) from donations where donations.donor_id = donors.id)'       
    else 'created_at'
  end
end

def sort_direction
  %w[asc desc].include?(params[:direction]) ?  params[:direction] : "asc"
end
```

and application_helper:

```
def sortable(column, title = nil)
  title ||= column.titleize
  css_class = (column == last_sort_column) ? "current #{sort_direction}" : nil
  direction = (column == last_sort_column && sort_direction == "asc") ? "desc" : "asc"
  link_to title, params.merge(:sort => column, :direction => direction, :page => nil), {:class => css_class}
end
```

The addition of the last_sort_column is because  `sort_column` that gets sent into the order  by statement doesn't match the column name so it never remembered what you have sorted as asc or desc.

This allows me to put as crazy of a sql statement as I want into the sort, but still completely prevents any possibility of sql injection since the url will only show the actual names of the columns.  If something other than the valid options I have allowed are entered, it defaults to created_at and throws away the bogus values.

I was actually surprised at how fast this was sorting over 100k rows linked to another 200k rows.

Answer (score 0):

Simplest case:

```
<% sorted_donors = @unsorted_donors.sort_by{ |donor| donor.who_donated } %>
```

Read more about sort_by here: http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.2/Enumerable.html#method-i-sort_by

Like I said, throwing this code directly into a view is the ugliest, yet easiest way of getting the sort you want. If you're doing pagination, you'll need to do the sorting in the controller before paginating, etc... but this snippet should at least get you moving in the right direction.

Comment: Hmmm... that would work, but I agree it is pretty ugly.  I am thinking about going with using jquery tablesorter which works great when you only have a few rows to work with... but I have over 200k rows that might be part of it.  I was using will_paginate which works great for having the controller pull in what I need, but it doesn't really work well with the jquery tablesorter.  The pager that comes with tablesorter is ok, but takes too long to load when they are lots of rows.  I think I might have to come up with a better way to reduce the rows of data the user would like to see.

Comment: I don't think there's anything ugly about the sort itself. That idiom of passing in a block to an internal iterator is pretty integral to how many Enumerable methods work. You'll learn to love it. It just shouldn't be in the view.  I wrote it that way so I could fit the entire thing in one atomic unit to illustrate how it works.  Good luck to you, though.  If you find something cleaner looking, please share.

Comment: Oh, I forgot to mention that you can further shorten that to "sorted_donors = @unsorted_donors.sort_by(&:who_donated)" but to someone not familiar with sort_by, that really gives no clue as to what's really happening there.